# Is there a way to define a complex objective function in an R optimizer?

Tags: r, optimization, ompr

In R, I am trying to optimize the following : choose rows which maximize the number of columns whose sum exceeds a certain value which varies by column + some other basic constraints on the row selections.

Is there anything out there in R which allows you to incorporate logic into an objective function? ie maximize countif ( sum(value column) > target value for column )  over ~10k columns choosing 5 rows with ~ 500 row choices.

Simple example: Grab the combo of 4 rows below whose col sum exceeds the target more frequently than any other combo of 4 rows.

```
  +--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
    |   x    | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10 |
    +--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
    | row1   |   82 |   73 |   50 |   11 |   76 |   12 |   46 |   64 |    5 |    44 |
    | row2   |    2 |   33 |   35 |   55 |   52 |   18 |   13 |   86 |   72 |    39 |
    | row3   |   94 |    5 |   10 |   21 |   90 |   62 |   54 |   54 |    7 |    17 |
    | row4   |   27 |   10 |   28 |   87 |   27 |   83 |   62 |   56 |   54 |    86 |
    | row5   |   17 |   50 |   34 |   30 |   80 |    7 |   96 |   91 |   32 |    21 |
    | row6   |   73 |   75 |   32 |   71 |   37 |    1 |   13 |   76 |   10 |    34 |
    | row7   |   98 |   13 |   87 |   49 |   27 |   90 |   28 |   75 |   55 |    21 |
    | row8   |   45 |   54 |   25 |    1 |    3 |   75 |   84 |   76 |    9 |    87 |
    | row9   |   40 |   87 |   44 |   20 |   97 |   28 |   88 |   14 |   66 |    77 |
    | row10  |   18 |   28 |   21 |   35 |   22 |    9 |   37 |   58 |   82 |    97 |
    | target |  200 |  100 |  125 |  135|  250 |  89 |  109 |  210|  184 |   178 |
    +--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

EDIT + Update: I implemented the following using ompr, ROI, and some Big M logic.

```
nr <- 10 # number of rows
nt <- 15 # number of target columns
vals <- matrix(sample.int(nr*nt, nr*nt), nrow=nr, ncol=nt)

targets <- vector(length=nt)
targets[1:nt] <- 4*mean(vals)


model <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i], i = 1:nr, type = "binary") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i], i = 1:nr)==4)%>%
  add_variable(A[j], j = 1:nt, type = "binary") %>%
  add_variable(s[j], j = 1:nt, type = "continuous",lb=0) %>%
  add_constraint(s[j] <= 9999999*A[j], j =1:nt)%>%
  add_constraint(s[j] >= A[j], j =1:nt)%>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(vals[i,j]*x[i], i = 1:nr) + A[j] + s[j] >= targets[j], j=1:nt) %>%    
    set_objective(sum_expr(-9999999*A[j], i = 1:nr, j = 1:nt), "max")

model <- solve_model(model,with_ROI(solver = "glpk"))
```

The model works great for small problems, including those where no solution exists which exceeds the target of every column.

However, the above returns Infeasible when I change the number of columns to even just 150. Given that I tested various scenarios on my smaller example, my hunch is that my model definition is OK...

Any suggestions as to why this is infeasible? Or maybe a more optimal way to define my model?

Comment: Interesting question! A minimal example would be helpful.

Comment: Added an example. Let me know if that helps or isn't clear.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but in the example, it would seem that no column sum could exceed its target?

Comment: Haha that might be true! I generated the data totally randomly and didn't look. Edited to change that

Comment: Sorry that is not true. I think my explanations made it clear what I am trying to solve for, what you listed is not a solution for finding the optimal combination of rows. What you suggested, if I'm interpreting it correctly, would mean generating all combinations of rows and proceeding from there. While that is possible for something like the example with only 10 rows, it is not practical for my actual problem with ~500 rows (that would be 500*499*498*497*496 possible combos).

Comment: See my edited solution for some points regarding your edit and `r` model.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a Local-Search algorithm. It may give you only a "good" solution; but in exchange it is highly flexible.

Here is a sketch. Start with an arbitrary valid solution `x`, for instance
for your example data

```
x <- c(rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 6))
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Define an objective function:

```
obj_fun <- function(x, table, target, ...) {
    -sum(colSums(table[x, ]) >= target)
}
```

Given a table and a target vector, it selects the rows
defined in `x` and calculates the number of rowsums that
match or exceed the target. I write `-sum`
because I'll use an implementation that minimises an
objective function.

```
-obj_fun(x, table, target)
## [1] 7
```

So, for the chosen initial solution, 7 column sums are equal to or greater than the target.

Then you'll need a neighbourhood function. It takes a
solution x and returns a slightly changed version (a
"neighbour" of the original `x`). Here is a neighbour function
that changes a single row in `x`.

```
nb <- function(x, ...) {
    true  <- which( x)
    false <- which(!x)
  
    i <-  true[sample.int(length( true), size = 1)]
    j <- false[sample.int(length(false), size = 1)]
    x[i] <- FALSE
    x[j] <- TRUE
    x
}


x
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

nb(x)
## [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##     ^^^^^                                      ^^^^
```

Here is your data:

```
library("orgutils")
tt <- readOrg(text = "
    |   x    | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10 |
    |--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
    | row1   |   82 |   73 |   50 |   11 |   76 |   12 |   46 |   64 |    5 |    44 |
    | row2   |    2 |   33 |   35 |   55 |   52 |   18 |   13 |   86 |   72 |    39 |
    | row3   |   94 |    5 |   10 |   21 |   90 |   62 |   54 |   54 |    7 |    17 |
    | row4   |   27 |   10 |   28 |   87 |   27 |   83 |   62 |   56 |   54 |    86 |
    | row5   |   17 |   50 |   34 |   30 |   80 |    7 |   96 |   91 |   32 |    21 |
    | row6   |   73 |   75 |   32 |   71 |   37 |    1 |   13 |   76 |   10 |    34 |
    | row7   |   98 |   13 |   87 |   49 |   27 |   90 |   28 |   75 |   55 |    21 |
    | row8   |   45 |   54 |   25 |    1 |    3 |   75 |   84 |   76 |    9 |    87 |
    | row9   |   40 |   87 |   44 |   20 |   97 |   28 |   88 |   14 |   66 |    77 |
    | row10  |   18 |   28 |   21 |   35 |   22 |    9 |   37 |   58 |   82 |    97 |
    | target |  200 |  100 |  125 |   135|  250  |  89 |  109 |   210|  184 |   178 |
")


table  <- tt[1:10, -1]
target <- tt[11,   -1]
```

Run the search; in this case, with an algorithm called
"Threshold Accepting". I use the implementation in package [NMOF](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF) (which I maintain).

```
library("NMOF")
x0 <- c(rep(TRUE, 4), rep(FALSE, 6))
sol <- TAopt(obj_fun,
             list(neighbour = nb,     ## neighbourhood fun
          x0 = sample(x0),    ## initial solution
          nI = 1000,          ## iterations
                  OF.target = -ncol(target)  ## when to stop
                 ),
             target = target,
             table = as.matrix(table))

rbind(Sums = colSums(table[sol$xbest, ]), Target = target)       
##        col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
## Sums    222  206  216  135  252  148  175  239  198   181
## Target  200  100  125  135  250   89  109  210  184   178
```

As I said, this is a only sketch, and depending on how
large and important your actual problem is, there are a number
of points to consider:

- most importantly: `nI` sets the number of search
  iterations. 1000 is the default, but you'll definitely
  want to play around with this number.
- there may be cases (i.e. datasets) for which the
  objective function does not provide good guidance: if
  selecting different rows does not change the number
  of columns for which the target is met, the algorithm
  cannot judge if a new solution is better than the
  previous one. Thus, adding more-continuous guidance
  (e.g. via some distance-to-target) may help.
- updating: the computation above actually does a lot
  that's not necessary. When a new candidate solution
  is evaluated, there would actually be no need to
  recompute the full column sums.  Instead, only adjust
  the previous solution's sums by the changed
  rows. (For a small dataset, this won't matter much.)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite what you asked as it is cast in `python`, but perhaps it will show you the approach to doing this with Integer Programming.  You should be able to replicate this in R as there are bindings in R for several solvers, including CBC, which is the one I'm using below, which is suitable for Integer Programs.

I'm also using `pyomo` to frame up the math model for the solver.  I think with a little research, you could find equivalent way to do this in R.  The syntax at the start is just to ingest the data (which I just pasted into a .csv file).  The rest should be readable.

The good/bad...

This solves almost immediately for your toy problem.  It can be shown that 5 rows can exceed all column totals.

For many more columns, it can bog down greatly.  I did a couple tests with large matrices of random numbers....  This is very challenging for the solver because it cannot identify "good" rows easily.  I can get it to solve for 500x100 with random values (and the total row randomized and multiplied by 5 (the number of selections....just to make it challenging) only in reasonable time by relaxing the tolerance on the solution.

If you really have 10K columns, there are only a couple ways this could work...  1.  You have several rows that can cover all the column totals (solver should discover this quickly) or 2. there is some pattern (other than random noise) to the data/totals that can guide the solver, and 3.  Using a large ratio based gap (or time limit)

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)  # this is the data from the post

# uncomment this below for a randomized set of data
# df = pd.DataFrame(
#     data = np.random.random(size=(500,100)))
# df.iloc[-1] = df.iloc[-1]*5

# convert to dictionary
data = df.iloc[:len(df)-1].stack().to_dict()
col_sums = df.iloc[len(df)-1].to_dict()

limit = 5  # max number or rows selected

m = pyo.ConcreteModel('row picker')

### SETS
m.R = pyo.Set(initialize=range(len(df)-1))
m.C = pyo.Set(initialize=range(len(df.columns)))

### Params
m.val = pyo.Param(m.R, m.C, initialize=data)
m.tots = pyo.Param(m.C, initialize=col_sums)

### Variables
m.sel = pyo.Var(m.R, domain=pyo.Binary)  # indicator for which rows are selected
m.abv = pyo.Var(m.C, domain=pyo.Binary)  # indicator for which column is above total

### OBJECTIVE
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(m.abv[c] for c in m.C), sense=pyo.maximize)

### CONSTRAINTS
# limit the total number of selections...
m.sel_limit = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(m.sel[r] for r in m.R) <= limit)

# link the indicator variable to the column sum 
def c_sum(m, c):
    return sum(m.val[r, c] * m.sel[r] for r in m.R) >= m.tots[c] * m.abv[c]
m.col_sum = pyo.Constraint(m.C, rule=c_sum)

### SOLVE
print("...built... solving...")
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc', options={'ratio': 0.05})
result = solver.solve(m)
print(result)

### Inspect answer ...
print("rows to select: ")
for r in m.R:
    if m.sel[r]:
        print(r, end=', ')

print("\ncolumn sums from those rows")
tots = [sum(m.val[r,c]*m.sel[r].value for r in m.R) for c in m.C]
print(tots)
print(f'percentage of column totals exceeded:  {len([1 for c in m.C if m.abv[c]])/len(m.C)*100:0.2f}%')
```

#### Yields:

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: -10.0
  Upper bound: -10.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 11
  Number of variables: 20
  Number of binary variables: 20
  Number of integer variables: 20
  Number of nonzeros: 10
  Sense: maximize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.0
  Wallclock time: 0.0
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.013128995895385742
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

rows to select: 
0, 2, 3, 8, 9, 
column sums from those rows
[261.0, 203.0, 153.0, 174.0, 312.0, 194.0, 287.0, 246.0, 214.0, 321.0]
percentage of column totals exceeded:  100.00%
[Finished in 845ms]
```

### Edit:

I see your edit follows similar pattern to the above solution.

The reason you are getting "INFEASIBLE" for larger instantiations is that your Big-M is no longer big enough when the values are bigger and more are summed.  You should pre-analyze your matrix and set `BIG_M` to be the maximal value in your target row, which will be big enough to cover any gap (by inspection).  That will keep you feasible without massive overshoot on `BIG_M` which has consequences also.

I tweaked a few things on your `r` model.  My `r` syntax is terrible, but try this out:

```
model <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i], i = 1:nr, type = "binary") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i], i = 1:nr)==4)%>%
  add_variable(A[j], j = 1:nt, type = "binary") %>%
  add_variable(s[j], j = 1:nt, type = "continuous",lb=0) %>%
  add_constraint(s[j] <= BIG_M*A[j], j =1:nt)%>%
  # NOT NEEDED:  add_constraint(s[j] >= A[j], j =1:nt)%>%
  # DON'T include A[j]:  add_constraint(sum_expr(vals[i,j]*x[i], i = 1:nr) + A[j] + s[j] >= targets[j], j=1:nt) %>%   
  add_constraint(sum_expr(vals[i,j]*x[i], i = 1:nr) + s[j] >= targets[j], j=1:nt) %>%  
  # REMOVE unneded indexing for i:  set_objective(sum_expr(A[j], i = 1:nr, j = 1:nt), "min")
  # and just minimize.  No need to multiply by a large constant here.
  set_objective(sum_expr(A[j], j = 1:nt), "min")

model <- solve_model(model,with_ROI(solver = "glpk"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is IMHO a linear programming modeling question: Can we formulate the problem as a "normalized" linear problem that can be solved by, for example, `ompr` or `ROI` (I would add `lpSolveAPI`)?

I believe it is possible, though I do not have the time to provide the full formulation. Here are some ideas:

As parameters, i.e. fixed values, we have

```
nr <- 10 # number of rows
nt <- 10 # number of target columns
vals <- matrix(sample.int(100, nr*nt), nrow=nr, ncol=nt)
targets <- sample.int(300, nt)
```

The decision variables we are interested in are `x[1...nr]` as binary variables (1 if the row is picked, 0 otherwise).

Obviously, one constraint would be `sum(x[i],i)==4` -- the numbers of rows we pick.

For the objective, I would introduce auxilliary variables, such as

```
y[j] = 1, if sum_{i=1..nr} x[i]*vals[i,j]>= targets[j]
```

(and 0 otherwise) for `j=1...nt`. Now this definition of `y` is not compatible with linear programming and needs to be linearized. If we can assume that `val[i,j]` and `targets[j]` are greater or equal to zero, then we can define `y[j]` as binary variables like this:

```
x'vals[,j]-t[j]*y[j] >= 0
```

(`x'y` is meant as inner product, i.e. `sum(x[i]*y[i], i)`.)
In the case `x'vals[,j]>=t[j]`, the value `y[j]==1` is valid. In the case `x'vals[,j]<t[j]`, `y[j]==0` is enforced.

With the objective `max sum(y[j],j)`, we should get a proper formulation of the problem. No big-M required. But additional assumptions on non-negativity introduced.

Comment: Hi, your suggestion to look at Big-M is incredibly helpful. I implemented something which works well for my small example, but comes out as infeasible when applied to larger sets.

I'm editing my initial post with my code.

Comment: Edited the answer for additional thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to solve here is called a "mixed integer program", and there's lots of (mostly commercial) software designed around it.

Your typical R functions such as `optim` are hardly any good for it due to the kind of constraints, but you can use specialized software (such as CBC) as long as you are able to frame the problem in a standard MIP structure (in this case the variables to optimize are binary variables for each row in your data).

As an alternative, you could also look at the package `nloptr` with its global derivate-free black-box optimizers, in which you can enter a function like this (setting bounds on the variables) and let it optimize it with some general-purpose heuristics.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looking at CBC and nloptr, I am still struggling to define my objective function. I understand my decision variables are the set of binary variables representing the inclusion of each row. However, I am seeking guidance on how to define "maximize countif ( sum(value column) > target value for column ) * (vector of binary decision variables)". As mentioned initially, I can define "maximize the column sums", but I don't know how to change that to "count the column sum as a 1 if it's > that col's target val, 0 if < target val" into the formulaic syntax required

Comment: Yes, that's hard to codify in standard form, and you'd probably have to introduce extra binary variables for the columns/thresholds plus inequality constraints according to the sum of row values per column (on the top of my head, I'm not 100% sure it'd be possible to frame as a simple MIP). You could also look at `or-tools` for python which allows framing the problem in a less standard way and makes the translation internally, or at R's ROI.